Characterising lattices $\Lambda\subseteq\mathbb{Z}^n$ whose union of translations by $b\in\{0,1\}^n$ recovers $\mathbb{Z}^n$
Given a lattice $\Lambda\subseteq\mathbb{Z}^n$ defined by $\Lambda = \{ Mx : x\in\mathbb{Z}^n \}$, let $\Lambda_b$ for $b\in \{0,1\}^n = B$ be the translation of $\Lambda$ by $b$. Call $M$ special whenever $\bigcup_{b\in B}\Lambda_b  = \mathbb{Z}^n$. Does there exist a nice characterisation of special matrices?

These lattices are called "cubiquitous" in low-dimensional topology (https://arxiv.org/abs/2212.06248). There is some literature on them, but not clear characterisation (as far as I can tell).

@MarcoGolla Thank you very much for this reference!

I had seen the more recent article, but missed the characterisation. Plus I don't know what a Hájos basis is.
